# Create objects on Ionic

Tags: angularjs, typescript, object, ionic-framework, instantiation

Good morning!
I've been working with Ionic for a few weeks and I thought I actually understood how typescript and angular works, but I've found myself with a weird trouble that I think it will be very silly...

I'm trying to create an object called `pendingWaybills` with some properties named `waybills`, `clients` and `clientWaybills`. The thing is that I'm creating it this way:

```
  pendingWaybills: {
    waybills: any
    clients: any,
    clientWaybills: any,
  };
```

I've also tried

```
  pendingWaybills: {
    "waybills": any,
    "clients": any,
    "clientWaybills": any,
  };
```

And some other ways, but when I try to assign a value to this properties I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'waybills' of undefined`

I've also tried to assign some string or integers just to see if it was about the data that I was trying to assign like `this.pendingWaybills.waybills = "Hi";` but I'm still getting the same error...

Would be glad to get some help as I think it's all about the way to create the object (and I also think it will be very silly) but I'm so stuck here.
Thank you!

Edit:
Here is where I try to assign the data to the object. (The variable data is a json)

```
  loadPendingWaybills(){
    this.loadClients(2)
      .then(data => {
        this.pendingWaybills.waybills = data;
        var preClients = this.pendingWaybills.waybills;
          this.clients = [];
            for(let i = 0;i < preClients.length; i++){
                if(this.pendingWaybills.clients.indexOf(preClients[i].descr1_sped) == -1){
                  this.pendingWaybills.clients.push(preClients[i].descr1_sped)
                }
            }
          this.pendingWaybills.clientWaybills = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < this.pendingWaybills.clients.length; i++){
              this.getWaybills(this.pendingWaybills.clients[i], 2)
                .then(data => {
                  if(this.pendingWaybills.clientWaybills[i] != data){
                    this.pendingWaybills.clientWaybills[i] = data;
                  }
                });
            }
      });
    }
```

Comment: can you put complete code where you instantiating and where you re assigning ?

Comment: Done! I'm not instantiating the object because in theory it's been created on the variables declaration and it's enough to assign it values,  right? (Or that's what I thought)

Comment: it is nested object you can not create right away when you declare it.  Example `var xxx = 'hi';` is fine. but if you do `var  xxx.yyy = 'hi'`  is not fine, as xxx is not defined before so yyy of xxx will cause error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in constructor

```
constructor() {
   this.pendingWaybills = {
     waybills: [],
     clients: [],
     clientWaybills: [],
  };
}
```

Some explanation

It is nested object you can not create right away when you declare it.

For example `var xxx = 'hi';` is fine. but if you do `var xxx.yyy = 'hi'` is not fine, as xxx is not defined before so yyy of xxx will cause error.

You can do

```
var xxx = {
   yyy: 'hi'
};
```

or you can do

```
var xxx = {};
xxx.yyy = 'hi';
```

Comment: Maybe would be good a little bit more of explanation but in the first instance, it was what made me understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Juli15 actually commented above in the original question up there. I'll put it here again.

Answer (score 2):

In Typescript, doing :

```js
pendingWaybills: {
    waybills: any;
    clients: any;
    clientWaybills: any;
};
```

will only set `pendingWaybills` variable type. To declare and assign value to the variable, you must do something like :

```js
pendingWaybills = { // note the "="
    waybills: something,
    clients: something,
    clientWaybills: something,
};
```

Comment: But if I can't assign a value yet? Because until I don't have waybills to assign I can't assign any information...

Comment: You can initialize its fields as empty arrays, as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an empty instance of the object, declaring the properties doesn't create the variable, it only tells your ide which properties it has:

```
public pendingWaybills = {
    waybills: []
    clients: [],
    clientWaybills: [],
};
```

Comment: But where I'm supposed to write this? On the same place where I initialize variables? Inside the constructor? As a function? (Thank you for the answer)